# Replace Splat in ReactiveUI with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector, reactiveui, splat

I'm trying to replace Splat in ReactiveUI with Simple Injector. I am using the package addon for SI. Here's my configuration:

```
    public void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        // I also registered other stuff in here with container.Register()
        // but this code has been removed in the question.
        Locator.Current = new FuncDependencyResolver((service, contract) =>
        {
            if (contract != null) return container.GetAllInstances(service);
            var items = container.GetAllInstances(service);
            var list = items.ToList();
            return list;
        },
        (factory, service, contract) =>
        {
            container.AppendToCollection(service, Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(service,   container));
        });
    }
```

Here's what I put in my view's constructor:

```
// Bind code inside View.
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.OutputDirectory, v => v.comboBoxAdvOutputFolder.Text);
```

As soon as I use Bind in my project, this throws an exception: "An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Project1.Windows.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: The type initializer for 'ReactiveUI.BindingMixins' threw an exception."

It also looks like the ViewModel remains null when I replace Locator.Current this way.

Edit: I think I made a slight mistake in the code. Here's the modified version:

```
        Locator.Current = new FuncDependencyResolver((service, contract) =>
        {
            return container.GetAllInstances(service);
        },
        (factory, service, contract) =>
        {
            container.AppendToCollection(service, Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(service, factory, container));
        });
```

Edit:
looks like the problem is that Simple Injector's containers cannot be modified after GetAllInstances is called, and I guess FuncDependencyResolver does this. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't completely replace Splat with SimpleInjector. I had to keep the IMutableDependencyResolver around and reference it in a custom FuncDependencyResolver.  The Locator.Current essentially defers to Splat first, then to SimpleInjector.  This works well as RxUI uses Locator.Current.  All of my classes are registered solely in SimpleInjector and don't use Locator.Current.

```
SplatResolver = Locator.CurrentMutable;
var customResolver = new FuncDependencyResolver((service, contract) =>
{
    IEnumerable<Object> services = null;
    services = SplatResolver.GetServices(service, contract);
    if (services == null || services.Count() == 0)
    {
        var svc = containerSI.GetInstance(service);
        if (svc != null)
        {
            services = new Object[] { svc };
        }
    }
    if (services == null || services.Count() == 0)
    {
        services = containerSI.GetAllInstances(service); // only applies services registered with .RegisterCollection()
    }
    return services;
}, (factory, service, contract) =>
{
    SplatResolver.Register(factory, service, contract);

    try
    {
        containerSI.Register(service, factory);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        // certain services are registered multiple times by RxUI.  For now, ignore them.
        //ICreatesObservableForProperty
        Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
    }
});

Locator.Current = customResolver;
```